# How do you say "carpet" in Mexican Spanish?

Tags: traducción, méxico, estados-unidos

The carpet I am referring to is a large cloth that spans the entire room. It is not an area rug.

[image: carpet]

I have a Mexican contractor that is renovating my house. When referring to carpet, I always say to him `alfombra`, but he always says back to me `carpeta`. It sounds like a spinoff of the English equivalent. It is strange that Google translator says `carpeta` is not carpet but rather a folder. Am I saying carpet wrong or is my contractor saying it wrong?

Comment: `Carpeta` sounds like a rip-off from English to me. In Spain, we call it `moqueta`. The RAE dictionary says `moqueta` is a kind of cloth used for carpets, but we certainly use it to mean a "whole room carpet".

Comment: Keep in mind that Mexican Spanish and U.S. Spanish are distinct dialects.

Comment: I don't think there is a specific term in mexican spanish for that. I have heard moqueta and alfombra. I haven't lived in mexico though so I'm not in a position to know. @Flimzy should know! :O)

Comment: Does he call his truck a camión or a troca?

Comment: @WalterMitty, I've heard the Spanglish term _Vacunar la carpeta_ to mean _Vacuum the carpet_ (not _vaccinate the folder_ which is what it would mean in Spanish), among NYC Puerto Ricans.

Comment: @deStrangis at some point, it becomes Spanglish.

Comment: This is called a "wall to wall carpet" (alfombra muro a muro.) Carpet or rug are usually the same thing in spanish, except that "rug" may have more localized names.

Comment: does he also say *"te llamo pa'tras"*? ;-)

Comment: Carpeta sounds just as bad as moqueta (which sounds like a rip-off from French to me).

Comment: Also, immigrant workers use stuff they hear and adapt it. The Brazilians where I live in the US say: estou bizzy for I'm busy instead of estou occupada. I think everyone should take a step back here. There are all sorts of socio-economic and educational forces in play here.

Comment: this is not a rant. but more like a social truth, when it comes to mexican americans don't trust in how they use their spanish. if they were raised in the US, is most likely they won't even know how to write or read it. and why is that ? because spanish is not studied as an official language in the US, so they will not have a reliable source in your country, so yeah, "Carpeta" is wrong, "Alfombra" is correct.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The *only* usual word for "carpet" in Mexican Spanish is **alfombra**.

I think that if any Mexican Spanish speaker says *carpeta* is beacause either he lives in the North border or he's been raised in a multicultural enviroment, in this case with American culture.

So, there are many "words" Mexican people from borders or people living in USA which they use in their daily life *adapting* English words to Spanish and such words are actually **wrong said**:

> **Parkear or parquear** *To park the car*
>   **Troca**  *Pick up*

These would be typical examples,

Comment: No, the word for what is asking would be "moqueta", spanning the entire room.

Comment: I never heard that word in my life, not in 3 mexican places I've lived for 21 years since I was born

Comment: @JoulSauron I've never heard moqueta.

Comment: "moqueta" is used (wrongly) in some parts of Spain.

Comment: Interesting! Where exactly @LeonardoHerrera? Andalucía?

Comment: @Diego - I don't know, but I've heard it more than once from spaniard friends...

Comment: De hecho `Troca` es mas bien un anglicismo de `Truck`

Comment: They call troca to any pick up truck in México. Not exactly every truck

Comment: Objectively false.  People in Mexico say "carpeta" all the time.  Me caga, but it is what it is.

Comment: @LeonardoHerrera There are two things wrong there, first it's not in some parts of Spain (in every part of Spain the word moqueta is known and used), and the second, it's not wrong. While moqueta describes the fabric it's made before, it's come to describe also the carpet that covers the entire floor, while alfombra is used for area rugs. Also I've never seen a spanish house with a moqueta ;)

Comment: @MyUserIsThis - it is wrong until they fix the RAE definition, isn't it?

Comment: @LeonardoHerrera I like to accept when a Spanish term is right when the usage is universal enough, for two reasons: the first one is that the RAE has come to fix definitions for words in the last years that are plainly stupid, not only not used in Spain but neither in the Spanish speaking countries of South America; the second is that, for example, slang words they accept, are biased towards Spanish from Spain because this is a Spanish institution, this meaning that if only RAE words are correct words, then half the countries in south america speak with most vocabulary wrong.

Comment: @LeonardoHerrera The last point specially is, I think, completely absurd, I don´t even think they pretend to be the right Spanish even when it's what it's supposed to be.

Comment: @MyUserIsThis I don't know, they take their time but usually get it right at the end. I only said so because it is *technically* wrong to use moqueta for carpet (even it is *factually* right.) I have no doubt they'll eventually accept that particular meaning.

Comment: such words are wrong said? Hmm. Well, there's troca, too. And "Tu ves bien" for You look good". I just heard that in La Querida del Centauro telenovela....moqueta is from the French word moquette=wall-to-wall carpet**ing**.

Comment: _Te ves bien_ (you look good) is not the same as _Tu vas bien_ (you're fine).

What I'm saying is, _tu ves bien_ doesn't make sense in Spanish :)

Answer (score 6):

In México you say "alfombra". Greetings

Answer (score 3):

Besides `alfombra` it's not uncommon in northern Mexico (at least in Chihuahua) to use `tapete` (while that mostly refers to `rug` it's also a valid word for `carpet`)

Comment: an area rug is a tapete. a carpet can be wall to wall or an area rug in English.

Answer (score 1):

I believe the term `carpeta` is used primarily in the U.S., and likely in northern regions of Mexico.  `Alfombra` is the preferred term in most of Mexico.

Comment: I am from Monterrey a northern city of Mexico and the preferred term is "alfombra". "carpeta" is used as a synonym of a folder.

Answer (score 1):

The language used by your contractor is not Spanish (be it Mexican Spanish or a dialect), but rather [Spanglish](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Spanglish).

In fact this is the very example used in [BBC article](http://news.bbc.co.uk/hi/spanish/misc/newsid_5414000/5414864.stm) describing the phenomenon.

> 'Tienes que vacuumclinear la carpeta en la yarda porque tiene un
>   damage'.

Comment: Mexican Spanish is not a dialect.

Comment: @c.p. Unless you want to argue that it's instead a collection of dialects, you're completely wrong.

Comment: @MichaelWolf You're quite funny :D (I should consider the possibility you're statement is serious, though.  In that case, care for providing the list of dialects you think there exist?)

Comment: So is troca Spanglish?

Answer (score 1):

Carpet = alfombra

I am Mexican and grew up in Tijuana. I have been living in USA for about 8 years and found out that a lot of Mexican people use *carpeta* to refer to a carpet. But that's wrong....

*Carpeta* in Mexico is a binder.

Comment: carpeta is also a folder.

Answer (score 1):

In the state of Veracruz, *alfombra* is used less than *tapete*.  *Tapete* is thinner and more affordable.  *Alfombra* is thicker and more luxurious.  It is probably more elegant looking and the *tapete* is more rustic looking.  Also, the *tapete* is probably smaller than the *alfombra*.

I never heard *carpeta*.  It may be that this workman picked it up from other workmen.  He might have gotten it from a so-called bilingual employee at the local Home Depot.  He might have gotten in the habit of using it because it made communicating with anglo clients easier.  Maybe he's from a region in Mexico where that term is generally used for carpets and rugs.

Answer (score 0):

I lived for 20 plus years in Cd. Juarez, Chihuahua. From what I remember "carpeta"  was the three-ring binder (not the "folder". In Juarez the "folder" was just called a "folder"). "Alfrombra" it was given to both the "carpet" and "area rug". But DarkAjax is right. In Chihuahua the "area rug" can also be called "tapete". At the same time the "welcome mat" or "doormat" was also called "tapete". Like I said before, that was back when I lived in Cd. Juarez......Damn, I didn't know it was this hard to be bilingual.

Comment: Well, a mat is also una estera.

Answer (score 0):

I've heard "carpeta" (yes, literally "folder," but used to mean wall-to-wall carpet) commonly in the Denver area.  I'd consider it to be a Spanglish term, typical not just among contractors, but maybe any at-home-Spanish-speakers who live someplace in the USA where wall-to-wall carpet is popular.  For what it's worth, "alfombra" seems to sound like "rug" to some Spanish-speakers around here.  To some extent, usage defines meaning, in my opinion, as much as I dislike certain trends.

Comment: @walen - Denver, CO, is the only Denver I've every heard of.  Is there another one somewhere else?  At any rate, I think OP's point of view was similar -- OP seemed to be living in the US, communicating with someone who was born and raised in Mexico.  By the way, I used to think of certain areas, including Colorado, as places that had a particularly large population of latinos, but nowadays I'm getting the feeling latinos are *everywhere*!  For example, I am in upstate New York; dairy farming is now employing lots of ...

Comment: ... latinos.  And what makes that type of work particularly tough is the isolation and the long hours.  12-hour shifts or more.

Comment: @Churri - Never heard of any of those places!  How about you? // Does the size of any of them come remotely close to the commonly known one?

Comment: @walen - I doubt he'd have omitted the state if it had been any other Denver.  // I got the distinct feeling from the post that this person is in the US.  It's hard to give you specific evidence that gave me this intuition, though.  I looked at a recent gardening post to see if my guess was off and found a mention of being in a certain hardiness zone in California. // I think I owe you an apology about something, that much is clear, but I don't know what bothered you.  I think my rambling comment was mainly intended to convey my impression that one could currently throw a dart at a map of ...

Comment: ... the US and find well-meaning anglos and patient latinos muddling along in communication attempts -- as opposed to twenty years ago, when I think the latino population distribution was patchier than now.  But I haven't looked at data.

Comment: considering size, in mexico a rug is a "tapete" a small carpet that doesn't cover a whole room, normally "tapetes" are limited by borders or are made in a specific size for multiple purposes, while an "alfombra" a carpet normally covers a whole room and is customaded for the room